# ActionView::Template::Error Unexpected token punc «(»

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

No matter what I try, I can never solve this little annoying issue. I guess we all hate it when our dev machine has no issues but once pushed to heroku, all hell broke loose.

I have narrowed this down to the asset pipeline. In heroku logs:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:» (line: 22951, col: 10, pos: 682164)

Which is caused by:

```
<%= image_tag("o-section/bird.jpg", height: "110", width: "110", class: "img-circle") %>
```

When, `production.rb`:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

If the above line is set to `false`, no `token punc «(»` etc but.....no image is shown! What?!

Inside my `production.rb` file:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.react.variant = :production
config.eager_load = true
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.log_level = :debug
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'foo.com' }
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

I was on Rails 5 and I thought it was a Rails 5 issue. Moved back to 4.2.5 and same.

Here is the html.erb, foundation 6:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 large-centered">
    <%= image_tag("o-section/bird.jpg", height: "110", width: "110", class: "img-circle") %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[SOLVED HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230740/heroku-crashing-with-rails-5-rc1/37248494#37248494)**

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote near the end of this line:

```
<div class="large-6 large-centered>
```

at the end of centered

Comment: No sorry, that's just a typo.