# Heroku crashing with Rails 5 rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have upgraded from rails 4 to 5. Great. Added Foundation 6 topbar, pushed to heroku. Nothing failed but website not loading. `heroku run logs` showed this:

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">
    <%= image_tag("o-section/mascot.svg") %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The error was:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Unexpected token punc «(», expected punc «:» (line: 23041, col: 10, pos: 685332) error

Is there an issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Let me close this. I can't explain why this works or used to work before adding a new image but...it works.

Looking back at the error, it was relating to a javascript function. I do not know what or where is `line: 23041` but I guess that is from a compiled file. So for a long story short, all my js functions looked something like this:

```
foo() {
 ...
}
```

I then wondered, what if I changed all to a "vanilla js function".:

```
foo: function() {
 ...
}
```

So basically the clue was `expected punc «:»` in which it wanted `foo: function(){...}`

After that, I `rake asset:precompile` and all was well.

Answer (score -1):

Your error says it does not expect a `(` and expects a `:` instead.

Try replacing:

```
<%= image_tag("o-section/mascot.svg") %>
```

with:

```
<%= image_tag: "o-section/mascot.svg" %>
```